# Any one thing: syntactic analysis

Tags: adjectives, pronouns, determiners

> *None remembered **any one** thing he’d said.*

[How should **any one** be analyzed here?](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/any+one)

Comment: Imagine it says "No one remembered a (any) single word (one thing) he had said."

Comment: This is a great example of how writing creates problems. In speech, we'd never pronounce it so that _any_ and _one_ would be analyzed as forming the word _anyone_. The noun phrase _any one thing_ is pronounced as three words with stress on _thing_, not on _any_, the way _anyone_ does. Of course in writing, you can't tell the difference; computational linguists figure that any written English sentence is multiply ambiguous. The longer sentences have dozens of parses.

Comment: "Any one" is not a constituent. Syntactically, "any one thing" is an NP consisting of the nominal "one thing" determined by the determinative "any". Note that although "one" is a determinative, its function is modifier within the nominal, i.e. "any [one thing]".

Comment: @JohnLawler Incidentally, Longman Pronunciation Dictionary reads: _anyone_ also weak form **ən-**.

Comment: @BillJ what meaning of **one** do you think is used here from these? https://www.wordreference.com/definition/one

Answer (score -1):

Sounds awkward, maybe regional. Not much to analyze.

“None” may be okay if it follows a preceding sentence, like this: *Many members were present. None remembered **a thing** he said*.